# Does closing a Stream close the BufferedReader source?

Tags: java, stream

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams have a BaseStream.close() method and implement AutoCloseable,
>   but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed
>   after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such
>   as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing.
>   Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating
>   functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream
>   does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a
>   try-with-resources statement.)

When I create a `Stream<String>` using the `lines()` method on a `BufferedReader` as seen below, does closing the `Stream` also close the `BufferedReader`?

```
try (Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())).lines()) {
  // Do stuff
}

// Is the BufferedReader, InputStreamReader and InputStream closed?
```

Some really quick tests I've tried say no (the `in` field of the `BufferedReader` is not `null`), but then I'm confused by the following sentence, since this example is I/O as well, right?

> Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such
>   as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing.

If not, do I need to close *both* instances, or will closing the `BufferedReader` suffice?

---

*Ideally, I'd like to return a `Stream<String>` from some method, without having the client worry about the readers. At the moment, I've created a `Stream` decorator which also closes the reader, but it's easier if that isn't necessary.*

Comment: Where do you test that the `BufferedReader` is closed? Inside the `try` block?

Comment: I have tested it after explicitly calling `close` on the `Stream`, and checked the field using the debugger. The autoclosing try is meant as an example of how I'd like to use it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072035/why-is-files-lines-and-similar-streams-not-automatically-closed/34073306#34073306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, seems it doesn't. As the stream is created using

```
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            iter, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
```

which doesn't pass any reference to the the `BufferedReader`

Comment: There is no call to `public static Stream<String> lines(Path path, Charset cs)` in the question. [`Reader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) is called.

Comment: This seems to be a compelling argument as to why the `BufferedReader` would not be closed from the `Stream`. Looking at the source of `lines`, I see no reason why the `Stream` must be closed, and I conclude that only the `BufferedReader` should be closed.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question - try `Files.lines(Path, Charset)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not reading from a file, but from a process stream.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to defer closing of the reader to the delivered Stream you need to invoke [Stream.onClose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-):

```java
static Stream<String> toStream(BufferedReader br){
    return br.lines().onClose(asUncheckedAutoCloseable(br));
}


static Runnable asUncheckedAutoCloseable(AutoCloseable ac) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            ac.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: edited your answer a bit... hope you don't mind - a well deserved 1+ from me

Answer (score 2):

In your question you don't show how you create the `Reader` that is the argument of `new BufferedReader(in)`. But from my own tests there is no reason to assume that the `Stream` closes this argument.

Doing the following should close everybody:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/foo.html")));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                Stream<String> lines = reader.lines()) {
            lines.forEach(System.out::println);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found this as well. I have added some additional information to the question.

Comment: Using `try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/foo.html"))) {...}` would be much simpler.

Comment: Keep in mind, Tagir, that the OP's use case isn't reading from a file, but instead from a process's `InputStream`.