# Closing mapped streams - what's the idea?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

It's well known that Javadoc says about `Stream` interface:

> Streams have a BaseStream.close() method and implement AutoCloseable,
> but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed
> after use. **Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such
> as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing**.
> Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating
> functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream
> does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a
> try-with-resources statement.)

Ok, but at the same time there are methods like `flatMapToInt` in this interface:

```
IntStream flatMapToInt(Function<? super T, ? extends IntStream> mapper);
```

for which Javadoc specification says:

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into
> this stream.

So, I didn't get the idea: if `IntStream` isn't designed to have IO channel in its source, why is it closed inside this method?

For example, `ReferencePipeline` implementation does it in this way:

```
try (IntStream result = mapper.apply(u)) {     
   if (result != null)
       result.sequential().forEach(downstreamAsInt);
}
```

More general question could be: should we care about closing streams like `IntStream` (or its descendants) or not? If not, then why does `flatMapTo*` care?

**EDIT** @Tunaki has provided me with a very interesting [email link](https://www.mail-archive.com/core-libs-dev%40openjdk.java.net/msg22872.html). But this all is about `flatMap`, where, I agree, we should close the stream in general case. But my question is about special cases: `flatMapToInt`, `flatMapToLong` and so on, where I don't see any necessity of closing streams.

**EDIT-2** @BrianGoetz is appealed here, because it is his cited email, therefore he is in the subject :)

Comment: Treating `flatMapToInt` differently from `flatMap` makes no sense.  An `IntStream` can hold resources too; just because what comes out of the tail end is `int`, doesn't mean the source didn't start with a non-memory resource.  For example, supposing one does `flatMapToInt` where each element is flatmapped to `Files.lines().mapToInt(String::length)`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general rule about resource handling is that [whoever is responsible for closing a resource is the one that opened it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073306/1743880). The `flatMap` operation is the only operation in the Stream API that opens a `Stream`, so it is the only operation that will close it.

Quoting from [this mail](https://www.mail-archive.com/core-libs-dev%40openjdk.java.net/msg22872.html), Brian Goetz said:

> To summarize, `flatMap()` is the only operation that internally closes the 
>   stream after its done, and for good reason -- it is the only case where 
>   the stream is effectively opened by the operation itself, and therefore 
>   should be closed by the operation too.  Any other streams are assumed to 
>   be opened by the caller, and therefore should be closed by the caller.

The example given is the following. Consider

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dir)) {
    Stream<String> stream = paths.flatMap(p ->  {
        try {
            return Files.lines(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

The method reference `Files::lines` returns a `Stream<String>` of the lines of the file. When the flat mapping operation is over, it is expected that the opened resource used to read the file is closed. The question is: closed by what? Well, closed by flatMap itself because it is the operation that opened the Stream in the first place.

`Files.lines` returns a Stream with a pre-registered close handler that closes the underlying `BufferedReader`. When the flatMap operation is done, this close handler is invoked and the resources are correctly released.

---

The reason this idea is backported to `flatMapTo*` operations is the same: adhering to the above rule that every resource allocated by a process should be closed by that process.

Just to show that you can build an `IntStream` which would have an underlying resource to close, consider the following Stream pipeline where each path is not flatmapped to its lines but to the number of character in each line.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dir)) {
    IntStream stream = paths.flatMapToInt(p ->  {
        try {
            return Files.lines(p).mapToInt(String::length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *Any other streams are assumed to be opened by the caller, and therefore should be closed by the caller* - this means we should operate with all streams (say some `list.stream()`) with `try-with-resourse` construction??

Comment: @Andremoniy It will be a no-op for the majority of Streams. The only one concerned are the one dealing with underlying resources that should be closed.

Comment: Ok, for `flatMap` I agree, but idea with `Int/LongStream`s remains

Comment: @Andremoniy I see 2 reasons: Consistency and the rule "thou shall close what thou opened"

Comment: Again, I feel my self bore, but I don't see here consistency. Because if they said: guys, don't worry about `IntStream`, it shouldn't be closed explicitly, and then they close it just for another rule. It looks like, as I said before,  superfluous overcautiousness. Like somebody just copied code from `flatMap` method and extended it to special cases.

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm afraid I won't be able to answer that (can only make guesses) as I'm not a JDK dev ;).