# Does the stream.spliterator() close the stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

Does the `stream.spliterator()` implicitly closes the `stream`, or there is a need to explicitly close it afterwards?

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
Spliterator<T> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
// Some low lever operation with the spliterator
stream.close(); // do we need to close?
```

At first glance, it seems that the `.spliterator()` method closes the `stream`, but without calling `stream.close()`. At least if I close it straight away after the `.spliterator()` method is invoked, it seems not affection the spliterator operations.

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c").limit(2);
Spliterator<T> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
stream.close();
// Some low lever operation with the spliterator
```

This question can be extended to other `stream` methods, for example, the `.findAny()`.

```
stream.findAny() // Can I assume that I don't need to close the stream?
stream.onClose(() -> System.out.println("hi!")).findAny()`
// when the `onClose()` action will be called?
```

The reason for that question is to have deep clarity when a `stream` needs explicitly to be closed, and in the cases where I don't need to explicitly close it, when the `onClose()` defined actions will take place?

Comment: Stream interface extends the AutoCloseable interface, so I guest the `onClose` actions will be called sometime when the garbage collector disposes the stream. However it's best practice to close it as soon as possible.

Comment: no, there is no garbage collector driven closing of the stream—and the results would be disastrous, if stream had such a finalizer. The underlying resource itself *may* have an automatic cleanup, but that depends on the resource. But that does not imply the execution of any close handler registered to the stream.

Comment: Just to add to details, here is a good insight over streams and [TWR by Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22929990/1746118)

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer, the argument of who is responsible to handle the exception in case of `exception` during the `close()` method make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java close() stream after a terminal operation is issued?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813637/why-doesnt-java-close-stream-after-a-terminal-operation-is-issued)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Terminal operations *never* close the stream. Closing has to be done manually. The only place where automatic closing happens is within the `flatMap` operation, where manual closing of the substreams usually created on-the-fly would be somewhere between hard and impossible.

This also applies to the `Stream.spliterator()` method. In your examples, it makes no difference because the streams created via `Stream.of(…)` do not need to be closed and have no `onClose()` operation registered by default.

You have to consult the documentation of the factory methods to find out when a stream need to be closed. E.g. like [`Files#lines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

See also [Does collect operation on Stream close the stream and underlying resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31171489/2711488) or [Does Java 8 `Stream.iterator()` auto-close the stream when it's done?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40935029/2711488)

Comment: Thanks @Holger, just for information, if a terminal operation leaves the stream in a unusable state (e.g. `.findAny()`), why does not the terminal operation close the stream itself before returning the value?

Comment: @Tet: it follows the principle that the responsibility of closing lies at the creator of the resource and the terminal operation did not allocate the resource. Likewise, an `InputStream` doesn’t close itself when you read the last byte.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing changed concerning the closing of `Stream`s in Java 9. You still need to manually do it if the underlying resource should be freed. You should never rely on the garbage collector to do it. The [docs](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) still say:

> Streams have a `BaseStream.close()` method and implement `AutoCloseable`. Operating on a stream after it has been closed will throw `IllegalStateException`. Most stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use, as they are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management. **Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel, such as those returned by `Files.lines(Path)`, will require closing. If a stream does require closing, it must be opened as a resource within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that it is closed promptly after its operations have completed.**

Answer (score 4):

The call to [`spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#spliterator--) method returns a **[`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)** for the elements of this stream and *its a terminal operation.*

To answer your question - No, the `spliterator` method or for that sake none of the other *terminal operations* also does not *close* the stream.

This stands documented for [terminal operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) as -

> After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is
>   considered consumed, and can no longer be used.... In almost all cases, terminal operations
>   are ***eager***, completing their traversal of the data source and
>   processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal
>   operations `iterator()` and `spliterator(`) *are not*; these are provided as
>   an "escape hatch" to enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline
>   traversals in the event that the existing operations are not
>   sufficient to the task.

Over closing the [`Stream`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) on another hand the docs state that:-

> Most stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use, as
>   they are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which
>   require no special resource management. Generally, only streams whose
>   source is an IO channel, such as those returned by [`Files.lines(Path)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-),
>   will require closing.

---

The [`AutoCloseable`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) states to match to it-

> It is possible, and in fact common, for a base class to implement
>   AutoCloseable even though *not all of its subclasses or instances* will
>   hold releasable resources.

which is how the BaseStream extends it and the [`close()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#close--) doesn't impact far more than the streams over the ones using the resources such as `Files.lines(...)`.

> However, when using facilities such as Stream that support both
>   I/O-based and non-I/O-based forms, try-with-resources blocks are in
>   general unnecessary when using non-I/O-based forms.

Answer (score 0):

The method `stream.spliterator()` does not close the `Stream`, like no other terminal operation. You may or may not know, if you need to close the `Stream`, that's still a big debate. I personally would like to have all terminal operations except `spliterator()` and `iterator()` to implicitly close the `Stream` for various reasons. There is no harm in doing so, since most implementations would simply do *nothing*.

You can find one implementation in the `java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline`. The close action that has been added when calling `stream.onClose(action)` will be called in the moment `stream.close()` is called.

I cannot tell you when a `Stream` explicitly needs to be closed, since the current policy is to document it at the method that returns the `Stream`, like `Files.list(Path)`:

> The returned stream contains a reference to an open directory. The directory is closed by closing the stream.
>   ...
>
> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or
>   similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directory
>   is closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

When you call `stream.spliterator()`, the returned `Spliterator` may be lazy (see also `AbstractPipeline.lazySpliterator(..)`), thus still needs to operate on the elements of the original `Stream`. If you close the `Stream` before traversing the elements of the `Spliterator`, you might get an exception or the `Spliterator` simply does not operate anymore.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(""))) {
        stream.onClose(() -> System.out.println("stream closed"));
        final Spliterator<Path> split = stream.spliterator();

        /*
         * uncomment this to see what happens when you close the
         * stream before you traverse the spliterator
         */
        // stream.close();

        split.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The problem is now, if you want to have a method that returns a `Spliterator`, the caller has no `close()` method that can be called on the `Spliterator`.