# Stream a list of n-integers from a file to create n object array

Tags: java, arrays

Assume each T object can be instantiated as

```
T tobj = new T(//int value);
```

So to create an array of T[ ] from integers in a file seperated by space I do the following:

```
 BufferedReader br;
 FileReader fr;
 int[] arr;
 try{               
        fr = new FileReader(fo); // assume "fo" file name
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        arr = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split("\\s")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

 }catch(SomeException e){//something else}

T[] tobjarr = new T[arr.length];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)){
        tobjarr[i] = new T(arr[i]);
    }
```

1.Is the above method efficient in terms of time and space usage?

2.Is there any other way? if so how does it compare to above method?

Comment: How many integers are contained in the file?  Regarding space usage, this wouldn't be efficient since the entire file is loaded into memory (assuming it's a single line).

Comment: A large number. Say > 10^6

Comment: I wouldn't say that's large in today's standards.  Your file would only be a few MB.  Unless you're working with billions, I wouldn't worry about performance that much.

Comment: Instead of `.toArray()`, do `.mapToObj(T::new).toArray(T[]::new)` and you can skip the temporary array and extra loop.

Comment: So if I were using billions >10^9 . What would I do then?

Comment: You would then need to process the data partially. Only in chunks as large that you can handle them with your limited memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general your approach is fine. However, you can do that with a **single stream cascade**. Compared to your original approach this saves you **one iteration**.

Also note that nowadays we read files using Javas new I/O API called **NIO**. One big advantage is that it offers `Stream` methods. For example the `Files#lines` method that returns a stream over all lines of the file, perfectly suited for your approach.

So all in all, here is the **complete** code:

```
String file = ...
Pattern separator = Pattern.compile("\\s");

try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {
    T[] values = lines                      // Stream<String> lines
        .flatMap(separator::splitAsStream)  // Stream<String> words
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)        // IntStream values
        .mapToObj(T::new)                   // Stream<T> valuesAsT
        .toArray(T[]::new);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

Note that this code is slightly different to yours, as yours will only process **one line** and mine **all lines**. You may change that if you don't want it:

```
List<T[]> valuesPerLine = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))  // Stream<String> lines
    .map(separator::splitAsStream)  // Stream<Stream<String>> wordsPerLine
    .map(lineStream -> {
        return lineStream                 // Stream<String> words
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  // IntStream values
            .mapToObj(T::new)             // Stream<T> valuesAsT
            .toArray(T[]::new);
    })                              // Stream<T[]> valuesPerLine
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The main difference to your original approach is that we can easily transform an `IntStream` into a `Stream<T>` by using `mapToObj(T::new)` (or just `map` if it's a regular stream and not `IntStream`) which passes the elements to the constructor. After that we collect `Stream<T>` into an array by using `toArray(T[]::new)`.

Comment: Mh, it seems that, though many methods of **NIO** throw `java.io.UncheckedIOException` instead of `java.io.IOException`, the `Files#lines` method forces you to catch the exception too, it throws an `java.io.IOException` according to its documentation and source code. I've updated the answer and added `try-catch`.

Comment: What if my data source is not non-interfering?

Comment: Better to use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for this:

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks, I thought `Files#lines` does this by itself. But apparently it does not: [Why is Files.lines (and similar Streams) not automatically closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072035/why-is-files-lines-and-similar-streams-not-automatically-closed)

Comment: @magpie Sorry, I didn't get you, can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: what if my stream source is modified periodically? Will this behave like Buffered Reader ?

Comment: @magpie `Files#lines` internally uses a `BufferedReader`, so it will be as efficient. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.lines%28java.nio.file.Path%29). The advantage is that it automatically closes the `BufferedReader` in error case and attaches any additional exception that occurs while closing, it simply provides a very **compact** solution for a very frequent need, reading files.

Answer (score 2):

```
T[] array = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split("\\s"))
    .map(s -> new T(Integer.parseInt(s)))
    .toArray(T[]::new)
```

EDIT: noticed that you're using a different delimiter