# Java NIO Files count() Method for Counting the Number of Lines

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, nio

I was using the below code to calculate the number of lines in a file.

```
long numberOfLines = Files.lines(filePath).count();
```

Based on the output of the above, if the number of lines is 1, then the record `delimiter` (extracted from the last character of the line) should be replaced by `<delimiter>\n`. The delimiter got replaced fine, but when I tried to delete this file after this operation, it did not work.

```
if (numberOfLines == 1) {
                String rawData = (new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath))).trim();
                String toReplace = rawData.substring(rawData.length() - 1);
                String outString = rawData.replaceAll(toReplace, toReplace + "\n");
                Files.delete(filePath);
            }
```

The file lied there in the filesystem having the same filesize which it had before the delete operation. I tried to open this file and it showed me an "Access Denied" error.

I replaced `Files.lines(filePath).count();` with a customized java method to count the number of lines using an InputStream and closing it in the end, and the delete operation was working fine.

Is this how `Files.lines(String)` should behave? It seems it is not closing the object which it used to access the file.

Comment: `Files.lines` do not close the stream [It is a design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072035/why-is-files-lines-and-similar-streams-not-automatically-closed)

Comment: *Warning:* [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) reads text as UTF-8, while [`new String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) uses the platform's default charset. *Inconsistent character set*.

Comment: @gtgaxiola did not know that this was done on purpose. Thank you for the info and link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `try-with-resources`

```
long numberofLines = 0;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(filePath)) {
        numberOfLines = stream.count();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //catch exception
}
```

Then you can continue with your logic but the stream should already be closed.