# If without converting the lines to string does the code work fine?

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream

If without converting the below lines to string can it work fine? Do I need to use the `Stream <String>` in front of the `lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\demo.txt"));` to convert the file lines into strings? Or it is unnecessary to do that ?

```
lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\demo.txt"));
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
lines.close();
```

I'm new to Java, I don't really know about the use of `Stream <String>` in the coding. Is it meant to convert the lines to strings or something else? So I posted this question.

Comment: Files.lines is already returning a string list (I'm pretty sure at least). If you mean storing it in a variable, you should if you plan to do more than one operation.

Comment: So if I write  `final Path data = Paths.get("c:\\demo.txt"); 
Files.lines(data).forEach(System.out::println);`    is there any wrong in the coding?

Comment: `try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\demo.txt")) { lines.forEach(System.out::println); }` is the correct way to safely close the stream and avoid using the variable after it has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Files#lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) already returns a `Stream<String>`. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: So if I write  `final Path data = Paths.get("c:\\demo.txt"); 
Files.lines(data).forEach(System.out::println);`    is there any wrong in the coding?

Comment: @李晓东 The only thing wrong there is that you won't be closing the file at the end. See, e.g., the [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34072035/2422776).

Comment: Do you mean that I will need to close the file in the end? is it the only mistake in this coding?

Comment: @李晓东 yes, exactly.