# How to close a java.util.Stream and use a terminal operation

Tags: java, java-stream

If I have a `java.util.Stream` that needs to be closed (once it's finished with), how can I both close it (by calling `close`) and call a terminal operation such as `count` or `collect` ?

For example:

```
java.nio.file.Files.lines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("myfile.txt"))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        //.close(); ???
```

(in this example calling close isn't critical, but let's say I have a Stream object with a critical close operation registered on the stream via onClose).

I guess you can store the stream in a temp var and close it, like this:

```
Stream<String> ss = java.nio.file.Files.lines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("myfile.txt"));
Set<String> lines = ss.collect(Collectors.toSet());
ss.close();
return lines;
```

but it seems a bit clunky. Is it always safe to close a stream in this fashion?

Comment: You could just do `new HashSet<String>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myfile.txt")))`, and forego the Stream entirely.

Comment: @NathanHughes I rarely assign streams to variables. As per my first example the stream is created, used, and discarded. Try-with-resources implies assigning the stream to a variable. My question is whether that's the only way to close a stream, regardless of whether you use t-w-r.

Comment: @VGR `Files.readAllLines` is just one example of a stream that needs to be closed. My question pertains to any such stream.

Comment: Fair enough.  To answer your question:  No, it is not possible to close a Stream or any other AutoCloseable without either placing it in a try-with-resources statement, or assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Highly related (and possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072035/why-is-files-lines-and-similar-streams-not-automatically-closed  (with a some good answers as to why it is like that).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks, Brian's explanation does make sense and trumps my sense of "it doesn't feel right".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See docs.

[8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

> If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

[12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path))

> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open file is closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

I think you might want to consider using a try-with-resources construct. Especially as the current one has evolved into "must".